# Delete record from multiple table with foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3 tables:

- Post
- Like
- Comment

Relation among tables are:

- Post table:     postid PK
- Like table:     LikeID PK, postid FK, CommentID FK
- Comment table:  CommentID PK,PostID FK, CommentReplybyID FK (Self join on commentid)

Now I have to delete post from post table but I am getting an error.

I am using this query below:

```
begin tran

declare @userid int = 68;
declare @postid int = 15;

delete from likes 
where postid = @postid and userid = @userid 

delete from comments 
where postid = @postid and userid = @userid

delete from post 
where postid = @postid and userid = @userid 

rollback tran
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "Comments_fk3". The conflict occurred in database "development-topthat", table "dbo.Comments", column 'CommentReplyID'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "Likes_fk1". The conflict occurred in database "development-topthat", table "dbo.Likes", column 'PostID'.

I need help in where I am doing wrong. How to achieve this?

Comment: You have foreign key constraints that you have to deal with.

Comment: yes I know, but how?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the `CommentReplyID` and self-join comment I suspect you have a nested relationship of some kind in the comments table.

You'll need delete the records where the `CommentReplyId` matches the comments your deleting.

```
begin tran

declare @userid int = 68;
declare @postid int = 15;

-- are you sure userid should be used here?
delete from likes where postid = @postid and userid = @userid 

delete from comments c1 join comments c2 on c2.CommentReplyId = c1.CommentId where c1.postid = @postid and c1.userid = @userid

delete from comments where postid =@postid and userid = @userid

delete from post where postid = @postid and userid = @userid 

rollback tran
```

Comment: Try doing the self-join delete from `comment` first, I imagine the latter error might go away. Alternatively, I suspect you might have records in the likes table for that `postid` where the `userid` is something different.